# Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, mkdir

Trying to create a new dir using:

```
$date = date('MDY');
$fileName = $date . '-organizations.xlsx';
$directory = "/guard/API/office/Storage/Custom Reports/";
if (!file_exists($directory) && !is_dir($directory)) {
    mkdir($directory, 0777, true);
}
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($directory . $fileName);
return $fileName;
```

But the error is:

`Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in \somedir\...`

Could it be an issue of permissions on my local dev machine? I will NOT be able to set up permissions on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the permissions of that folder. When you start a file path with `/`, it's looking in the very root of the server. If `/guard` doesn't exist, you won't be able to create anything because only root usually has the ability to modify `/`. If you want `guard` to be in the project directory, remove the `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you tried to make directory from root path. Try two way to fix error.

1.Change directory path from currently to right:

```php
$directory = __DIR__."/guard/API/office/Storage/Custom Reports/";
```

2. Try this as `root` user:

```bash
exec ('sudo mkdir -m 777 '.$directory);
```